# style.display = "none" not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function showTodos(e) {
  document.getElementById('modal_todos').style.display = "block";
}

function closeTodoDiv(e) {
  document.getElementById('modal_todos').style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class=" modal modal-todos" id="modal_todos">
  <button style="float: right; margin-top:3px;margin-right:8px;">x</button>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Add new Todo</button>
  <h2>dfdfdf</h2>
  <h2>dfdfdf</h2>
</div>
```

I can't close my popuped up div on button click.Can't understand why "none" is not working, though my showTodos() is working fine. Also the ID used in unique.

Comment: The `modal_todos` used twice. And, how do you call the functions?

Comment: `id` should be used as unique identifier per each element

Comment: @ChristianCarrillo sorry silly mistake, still can't fix the issue. updated my current code

Comment: @FZs edited that in my code and here too, still same issue

Comment: Ok, but we still don't know how do you call functions...

Comment: @FZs actually both the functions are called on click, as I check through console.log() something. Do I still need to update my code with how they are called?

Comment: Yes. You should provide a code, that **reproduces** the issue. If your code doesn't call the functions, we can't see why the called functions doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attach a click event for the buttons using the `onclick` attribute.

```js
function showTodos(e) {
  document.getElementById('modal_todos').style.display = "block";
}

function closeTodoDiv(e) {
  document.getElementById('modal_todos').style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
.modal {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.o-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal modal-todos" id="modal_todos">
  <!-- added onclick="closeTodoDiv()" -->
  <button style="float: right; margin-top:3px;margin-right:8px;" onclick="closeTodoDiv()">x</button>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Add new Todo</button>
  <h2>dfdfdf</h2>
  <h2>dfdfdf</h2>
</div>

<!-- button to open the modal. added onclick="showTodos()" -->
<button class="o-btn" onclick="showTodos()">open modal</button>
```

A modern and better approach is to use `addEventListener` method instead of the inline events and also to store a reference for the modal to improve performance.

```js
const modal = document.getElementById('modal_todos'),
  btnOpen = document.getElementById('open'),
  btnClose = document.getElementById('close');

btnOpen.addEventListener('click', () => modal.style.display = 'block');

btnClose.addEventListener('click', () => modal.style.display = 'none');
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.modal {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.o-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal modal-todos" id="modal_todos">
  <button style="float: right; margin-top:3px;margin-right:8px;" id="close">x</button>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Add new Todo</button>
  <h2>dfdfdf</h2>
  <h2>dfdfdf</h2>
</div>

<button class="o-btn" id="open">open modal</button>
```

Comment: it still doesn't work. Actually, my function is getting called without onclick also(checked it through printing something) so I don't think it's an issue.

Comment: btnClose event listener is still ain't firing up

Comment: damn got it, close id not unique, changed it and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You should use this logic using listeners on your buttons:

```js
const $modalTodos = document.getElementById('modal_todos')
const $btnOpenModal = document.getElementById('btn-open-modal')
const $btnCloseModal = document.getElementById('btn-close-modal')

$btnOpenModal.addEventListener('click', showTodos)

$btnCloseModal.addEventListener('click', closeTodoDiv)

function showTodos() {
  $modalTodos.style.display = "block";
}

function closeTodoDiv() {
  $modalTodos.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<button id="btn-open-modal">open</button>
<div class=" modal modal-todos" id="modal_todos">
  <button id="btn-close-modal" style="float: right; margin-top:3px;margin-right:8px;">x</button>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Add new Todo</button>
  <h2>dfdfdf</h2>
  <h2>dfdfdf</h2>
</div>
```